# Mapnik performance - large polyline dataset

Tags: postgis, shapefile, mapnik, performance

I'm working with a very large set of polylines - contour data - to be rendered with Mapnik. (The contours are generated using gdal_contour from SRTM data.)

At present I'm storing them in PostGIS and Mapnik reads them from there. However, I'm not convinced this is the best use of space or CPU.

Would there be a performance hit if Mapnik read the shapefiles directly (with an .index file, of course)?

What would be the best way to minimise storage requirements for such a large dataset? Are there any other formats I should be considering?

Comment: Shapefiles degrade when they near 2GB even indexed what size are the shapefiles individually? would leave the data in PostGIS but grid the vectors in gridded chunks like http://dimensionaledge.com/intro-vector-tiling-map-reduce-postgis/

Comment: Followup comment given lack of responses: I'm leaning towards using Mapbox-format vector tiles instead.